# Help me with my Halloween decoration

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The Halloween is upon us, and I haven't decorated my house yet, so I gonna need your help to do this task

**Input**
The input will be a list of 4 digits numbers, where each digit represent a portion of decoration:

```
EMBU
||||
|||+-upper decoration
||+-bottom decoration
|+-mouth/nose
+-eyes
```

Eyes:
0 - `°`
1 - `¯`
2 - `-`
3 - `^`
4 - `'`

Mouth/Nose
0 - `v`
1 - `w`
2 - `o`
3 - `_`
4 - `-`

Bottom decoration 
0 - nothing
1 - skeleton
2 - pumpkin

Upper decoration
0 - nothing
1 - flying bat
2 - resting bat
3 - spider

**Output**

Skeleton:
`(EME)`
`​ _|_ ​`
`/[|]\`
`​  | ​ ​`
`​ / \ ​`

Pumpkin
`​  ,  ​`
`(EME)`

Flying bat
`​     ​`
`​ ^"^ ​`

Resting bat
`​ ​ () ​`
`` ​ ​ ´` ​ ``

Spider
`​  |  ​`
`​ .|. ​`
`​ :": ​`

- Each decoration has a 5 character width
- Upper decorations start from the top
- Lower decorations start from the bottom
- If the spider is over the pumpkin or there is no bottom decoration the web length will be 3, if it's over the skeleton, the web length will be 1
- When the bottom decoration is `0` the first 2 digits are irrelevant
- Between each decoration there will be an empty column

**Example**
Input
`3123 ??02 1021 0310`
Output

```
   |     ()             ​
​   |     ´`   ^"^       ​
​  .|.              (°_°)
​  :":               _|_ ​
​                   /[|]\
​   ,           ,     |  ​
​ (^w^)       (¯v¯)  / \ ​
```

Trailing spaces at the end of each line are optional
Trailing newline at the end of the entire output is allowed

**Winning criteria**
This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer wins

Comment: Is input always valid, so no `9999`?

Comment: @KarlNapf yes, the input will always be valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>319</s> 315 bytes

```js
let f =

s=>[0,1].map(i=>s.map(([A,B,C,D],x)=>+(z=i?D:C)&&[...'01/21/5015/41211/91/65'.split`/`[z-(i?C+D-13?1:-2:-2)]].map((n,y)=>a[(i?y:6-y)*4+x]=' '+('      ^"^   ()   ´`  / \\   |   .|. /[|]\\ _|_ ('+(e='°¯-^'[A])+'vwo_-'[B]+e+')  ,   :": ').substr(p+=n*5,5),p=0)),a=Array(28).fill`      `)&&a.join``.match(/.{24}/g).join`
`

console.log(f(["3123","0002","1021","0310"]));
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java, <s>829</s>, 798

Yeah. Substantially improved thanks to Kevin Cruijssen and corvus_192.

```java
s->{String[]e=s.split(" ");char c[][]=new char[8][e.length*6],t,u,h='|';int y,x=2,i=0,j;for(String l:e){y=0;char[]p=l.toCharArray(),z=c[y];int a=p[0],b=p[1],f=p[2],d=p[3],k=x-1,m=x+1;t=a<49?'°':a<50?'¯':a<51?45:a<52?'^':39;u=(char)(b<50?b+70:b<51?111:b<52?95:39);if(d>50){z[x]=h;if(f!=49){y=2;c[1][x]=h;c[2][x]=h;}z=c[y];z[k]=46;z[m]=46;z=c[++y];z[k]=58;z[m]=58;z[x]=34;}if(d==50){z[x]=40;z[m]=41;c[++y][x]='´';c[y][m]=96;}if(d==49){z=c[++y];z[k]=94;z[x]=34;z[m]=94;}if(f>49){y=6;c[y][x]=44;}if(f>48){y=f>49?7:3;z=c[y++];z[x]=u;z[k]=t;z[m]=t;z[x-2]=40;z[x+2]=41;}if(f==49){z=c[y++];z[x]=h;z[k]=95;z[m]=95;z=c[y];z[x]=h;z[k]=91;z[m]=93;z[x-2]=47;c[y++][x+2]=92;c[y++][x]=h;c[y][k]=47;c[y][m]=92;}x+=6;}for(;i<8;i++){s="";for(j=0;j<c[0].length;){t=c[i][j++];s+=t<1?' ':t;}System.out.println(s);}};
```

the ungolfed version

```java
static void makeDecorations(String s){
    String[]e=s.split(" ");
    char c[][]=new char[8][e.length*6],t,u,h='|';
    int x=2,i=0,j,y;
    for(String l:e){
        y=0;
        char[]p=l.toCharArray(), z=c[y];
        int a=p[0],b=p[1],f=p[2],d=p[3],k=x-1,m=x+1;
        t=a<49?'°':a<50?'¯':a<51?45:a<52?'^':39;
        u=(char)(b<50?b+70:b<51?111:b<52?95:39);
        if(d>50){z[x]=h;
            if(f!=49){y=2;
                c[1][x]=h;
                c[2][x]=h;
            }
            z=c[y];
            z[k]=46;
            z[m]=46;
            z=c[++y];
            z[k]=58;
            z[m]=58;
            z[x]=34;
        }
        if(d==50){
            z[x]=40;
            z[m]=41;
            c[++y][x]='´';
            c[y][m]=96;
        }
            
        if(d==49){
            z=c[++y];
            z[k]=94;
            z[x]=34;
            z[m]=94;}
        if(f>49){
            y=6;
            c[y][x]=44;
        }
        if(f>48){
            y=f>49?7:3;
            z=c[y++];
            z[x]=u;
            z[k]=t;
            z[m]=t;
            z[x-2]=40;
            z[x+2]=41;
        }
        if(f==49){
            z=c[y++];
            z[x]=h;
            z[k]=95;
            z[m]=95;
            z=c[y];
            z[x]=h;
            z[k]=91;
            z[m]=93;
            z[x-2]=47;
            c[y++][x+2]=92;
            c[y++][x]=h;
            c[y][k]=47;
            c[y][m]=92;
        }
        x+=6;
    }
    for(;i<8;i++){
        s="";
        for(j=0;j<c[0].length;){
            t=c[i][j++];s+=t<1?32:t;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Favorite decoration (which apparently looks more evil in my console): terminator skeleton

```java
(-w-) 
 _|_  
/[|]\ 
  |   
 / \
```

Comment: You can save some bytes by defining a lambda instead of a full method

Comment: That initial "Yeah" made me laugh hard, I don't know why.

Comment: +1! Some things you can golf: `char[][]c=new char[8][e.length*6];char t,u,h='|';` -> `char c[][]=new char[8][e.length*6],t,u,h='|';`; `'-'` can be `45`; `'^'` can be 94; The space can be removed here: `if(f>48) {`; And I'm sure a lot more can be golfed, but it's a bit too much to go into more complex golfing. :)

Comment: Kevin and corvus: thanks, I'll take another go at it later when I have the time. I'm sure this can be dropped under 800, especially with a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 2.3.1, <strike>777</strike> 752 bytes

Edit_0: I totally missed out on some golfable variable usage and some other stuff.

```
@o=Array.new;$*.each_with_index do|j,i|a,e,n,b,u,q,r,z,y=0,j[0].to_i,j[1].to_i,j[2].to_i,j[3].to_i,['°','¯','-','^',"'"],['v','w','o','_',"-"],Array.new(7," "),"     ";g,h=[z,["(#{q[e]}#{r[n]}#{q[e]})","​ _|_ ​","/[|]\\","​  | ​ ​","​ / \\ ​"],["     ","​  ,  ","(#{q[e]}#{r[n]}#{q[e]})"]],[z,["​     ​","​ ^\"^ ​"],["​ ​ () ", "​ ​ ´` "],["​ .|. ​","​ :\": ​"]];2.times{h[3].unshift("  |  ​")}unless b==1;if b<1 && u<1;@o.push(z);elsif b<1;u<3 ? (a=5):(a=3);a.times{h[u].push(y)};@o.push(h[u]);elsif u<1;b==1 ? (a=2):(a=4);a.times{g[b].unshift(y)};@o.push(g[b]);elsif u>0;2.times{h[u].push(y)}if u<3&&b>1;@o.push(h[u]+g[b]);end;@o.push(z);end;@o.transpose.each do|v|;v.each do |w|;print w;end;print"\n";end
```

Takes in N number of variables of decorations. There's certainly some more golfing that can be done with this. I'm not that familiar with a lot of Ruby's tricks, but here's a shot at it! I'm also happy at being able to solve it.

### Un-golfed

```
@output = Array.new
$*.each_with_index do |j, i|
  # output decoration combo
  s = 0

  # set up vars for decoration input
  e = j[0].to_i
  n = j[1].to_i
  b = j[2].to_i
  u = j[3].to_i

  # Setup decorations/misc
  eyes = ['°','¯','-','^',"'"]
  nose = ['v','w','o','_',"-"]
  nothing = Array.new(7, " ")
  skeleton = ["(#{eyes[e]}#{nose[n]}#{eyes[e]})", "​ _|_ ​", "/[|]\\", "​  | ​ ​", "​ / \\ ​"]
  pumpkin = ["     ", "​  ,  ", "(#{eyes[e]}#{nose[n]}#{eyes[e]})"]
  fbat = ["​     ​", "​ ^\"^ ​"]
  rbat = ["​ ​ () ", "​ ​ ´` "]
  spider = ["​  |  ​", "​ .|. ​", "​ :\": ​"]
  spider.unshift("  |  ​") unless b == 1
  a = "     "
  bot = [nothing, skeleton, pumpkin]
  top = [nothing, fbat, rbat, spider]

  # if bottom and upper are empty
  if b < 1 && u < 1
    @output.push(nothing)
  # if bottom is empty
  elsif b < 1
    u < 2 ? (s = 3) : (s = 5)
    s.times {top[u].push(a)}
    @output.push(top[u])
  # if upper is empty
  elsif u < 1
    # put in white space before the decorations
    b == 1 ? (s = 2) : (s = 5)
    s.times {bot[b].unshift(a)}
    @output.push(bot[b])
  # if there's an upper decoration
  elsif u > 0
    # put in the top deco
    2.times {top[u].push(a)} if u < 3 && b > 1
    @output.push(top[u] + bot[b])
  end
  # Input the empty column
  @output.push(nothing)
end

# Transpose the array of arrays so that
# instead of outputting each line of a single each decoration
# what's output is each line of each decoration.
# Example:
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
# [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
@output.transpose.each do |data|
   data.each do |data1|
     print data1
   end
   print "\n"
end
```

The following:

```
ruby deco_g.rb 0000 0001 0002 0003 1110 1111 1112 1113 2220 2221 2222 2223 3310 3312 3321 3323
```

Outputs this:

```
          ()    |                 ()   .|.                ()    |           ()          |
   ^"^    ´`    |          ^"^    ´`   :":         ^"^    ´`    |           ´`   ^"^    |
               .|.  (¯w¯) (¯w¯) (¯w¯) (¯w¯)                    .|.  (^_^) (^_^)        .|.
               :":   _|_   _|_   _|_   _|_                     :":   _|_   _|_         :":
                    /[|]\ /[|]\ /[|]\ /[|]\                         /[|]\ /[|]\
                      |     |     |     |     ,     ,     ,     ,     |     |     ,     ,
                     / \   / \   / \   / \  (-o-) (-o-) (-o-) (-o-)  / \   / \  (^_^) (^_^)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 331 bytes""

```python
B,I,l,s=' '*5,'  |  ',' .|. ',' :": '
r=[]
for x in inputtt:m,n,b,u=(int(y)for y in x);e="°¯-^'"[m];H='('+e+"vwo_-"[n]+e+')';r+=[[[B,B,'  () ',[I,l,I][b]][u],[B,' ^"^ ','  ´` ',[I,s,I][b]][u],[[B,l][u==3],H][b==1],[[B,s][u==3],' _|_ '][b==1]]+[[B]*3,['/[|]\\',I,' / \ ',],[B,'  ,  ',H]][b]]
print'\n'.join(map(' '.join,zip(*r)))
```

Takes input as list of strings

-

#### Example

Input:
`["1212","4321","0123","1102","0020","1010","0101","2113"]`

Output:

```
  ()          |     ()                     .|. 
  ´`   ^"^    |     ´`               ^"^   :": 
(¯o¯)        .|.              (¯v¯)       (-w-)
 _|_         :":               _|_         _|_ 
/[|]\                         /[|]\       /[|]\
  |     ,     ,           ,     |           |  
 / \  ('_') (°w°)       (°v°)  / \         / \
```